# How to recode data using dplyr::recode when variables have a space

Tags: r, dplyr, recode

I have

```
myColors <- c("red", "purple", "blue", "blue", "orange", "red", "orange")
library(dplyr)
recode(myColors, red="rot", blue="blau", purple="violett")
```

However if my data have spaces in them this method does not work

```
myColors <- c("Color red", "Color purple", "Color blue", "Color blue", "Color orange", "Color red", "Color orange")
recode(myColors, Color red="rot", Color blue="blau", Color purple="violett")
```

Is there anything I can do to fix this other than changing the data?

Comment: Wrap in quotes, i.e. `"Color red"="rot"`

Comment: wow I didnt think of this. Please make it an answer so that I can close

Comment: You can use backticks("``")  for non-syntactic names in R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your categories have a space or ... you have to wrap them in quotes or backticks:

```r
myColors <- c("Color red", "Color purple", "Color blue", "Color blue", "Color orange", "Color red", "Color orange")

dplyr::recode(myColors, "Color red" = "rot", `Color blue` = "blau", "Color purple" = "violett")
#> [1] "rot"          "violett"      "blau"         "blau"         "Color orange"
#> [6] "rot"          "Color orange"
```